# Prove $8 \cos{(x)}\cos{(2x)}\cos{(3x)} - 1 = \dfrac{\sin{(7x)}}{\sin{(x)}}$

Tags: trigonometry

How do you prove that
$8 \cos{(x)}\cos{(2x)}\cos{(3x)} - 1 = \dfrac{\sin{(7x)}}{\sin{(x)}}$?

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$8 \sin x\cos{(x)}\cos{(2x)}\cos{(3x)} =4\sin(2x)\cos(2x)\cos(3x)=2\sin(4x)\cos(3x)$$
Moreover

$$\sin x+\sin(7x)=2\sin\left(\frac{x+7x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{7x-x}{2}\right)=\cdots$$
and the result follows easily.

Comment: The last identity is http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both sides by $\sin x$, then

$$2\cos x \sin x = \sin 2x$$

$$2\cos 2x \sin 2x = \sin 4x$$

$$2\sin 4x \cos 3x = \sin 7x + \sin x$$